# Recover data from a FAT32 hard disk?

Tags: 12.04, hard-drive, data-recovery

I have connected a failed hard disk which has a detectable FAT32 filesystem. I Dont know the nature of the damage. What is the easiest way to recover the data from the drive?

Comment: I think this topic, already exists.

See this link: [http://askubuntu.com/questions/147228/how-to-repair-fat32-corrupted-file-system][1] 


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/147228/how-to-repair-fat32-corrupted-file-system

Comment: He is not asking how to repair fat32 corrupted file system.

Comment: Of course he ask. If you want to recover a file system, you must first try to repair the file system.

Comment: No that not correct.  You can recover data without repairing the file system.  Its called RAW Recovery.  I have done it  over 100 times.  Part of what I do for a living.

Comment: So why the down-vote?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3681/discussion-between-mitch-and-subv3rsion)

Comment: You must try to be more specific, so you can help the user.
Edit your question, and be more specific.

Comment: Try a Proprietary Software Called Easus Data Recovery Wizard.. It recovered around 250 GB of Data after I accidentally deleted 2 partitions..

Answer (score 9):

Quoted:

There are lots of utilities to recover deleted files, but what if you can’t boot up your computer, or the whole drive has been formatted? We’ll show you some tools that will dig deep and recover the most elusive deleted files, or even whole hard drive partitions.

**Testdisk** includes TestDisk, which can recover lost partitions and repair boot sectors, and PhotoRec, which can recover many different types of files from tons of different file systems.

**Foremost**, originally developed by the US Air Force Office of Special Investigations, recovers files based on their headers and other internal structures. Foremost operates on hard drives or drive image files generated by various tools.

**Scalpel** performs the same functions as foremost, but is focused on enhanced performance and lower memory usage. Scalpel may run better if you have an older machine with less RAM.

[Recover Data Like a Forensics Expert Using an Ubuntu Live CD](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15761/recover-data-like-a-forensics-expert-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/)

Or you can use [Redo Backup and Recovery](http://redobackup.org/)

Redo Backup and Recovery is a GPLv3 Perl script built with a GTK2+ interface designed in Glade. It is simply a front end to partclone, which performs the actual backup and restore. The live CD is built on Ubuntu to provide a graphical user interface and unmodified binaries of each program, but the script will run on any Linux platform that has the required programs installed. The Perl source code for the backup script is contained on the live CD itself.

Redo doesn't need Windows. Download and burn the ISO, place it in your CD-ROM drive, and reboot your machine. The system will load a complete mini operating system with a point-and-click user interface into your computer's memory, without writing any information to your hard drive. Then you will be able to perform backup, restore and recovery actions—guaranteed—even if you aren't able to boot into your regular operating system.

Source: [howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15761/recover-data-like-a-forensics-expert-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/) and  [Redo](http://redobackup.org/)

Comment: With one seriously corrupted microsd card I had to use both `foremost` and `photorec`. Neither could restore all files but `foremost` seemed to better with JPEG and PNG images whereas photorec was better with multimedia files. With `photorec` tried to run it repeatedly with different sector sizes (512 and 4096 getting best results for badly corrupted FAT32 partition).