# I cancelled gparted operation ,what to do next?

Tags: filesystem, data-recovery, gparted, format

I cancelled gparted operation by mistake.Now one of the partition became corrupted,what to next? Should I format it? Data is important to me

Edit1: I tried to recover partition using testdisk and successfully recovered losted partition,but another partition(an extended partition containing ubuntus ) gone,How to recover it? :)

Edit2:

testdisk saved my life ,it recovered all my partition without losing data

Comment: I think you can still recover

Comment: I agree with Takkat.  If you need more, see my post http://askubuntu.com/questions/147367/recover-data-from-a-fat32-hard-disk/147378#147378

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to recover your partition with [testdisk](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/testdisk) [image: Install testdisk]. Take the time to go through the [Guide from CGSecurity](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) that leads you through the steps you will have to take.

Take extra care to not overwrite other existing partitions. If your backups are old, it may now be a good idea to backup other partitions on that drive before you try recovery. Running testdisk is also possible on an image of your drive.

In case the partition recovery fails then you are able to recover your files with **photorec** (which is installed with testdisk). This will recover the content from all your data files but directories, file names, and permissions will unforunately be lost.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay ,should I format that partition before proceed?

Comment: No, format is not needed - just leave it as is and try to recover the partition tables.

Comment: That partition recovered ,but another(my linux partition gone) ;(

Comment: Maybe ,but that partition was ok before testdisk :(

Comment: Now I am trying recover via deeper search option in testdisk . It show many partitions :s

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaanks ,testdisk saved my life :)