# Hard Drive recovery, corrupt file system

Tags: data-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recover data from a FAT32 hard disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147367/recover-data-from-a-fat32-hard-disk)

My external hard drive (500GB WD "My Passport") show's no files, yet it is half full, I think it is also FAT32, not NTFS, as in, it was* NTFS I think, (not 100% sure, but I bought it NTFS, it should be NTFS) and now it shows FAT32 and my files cannot be seen.

What is the easiest and quickest way to get over 230GB of files back on this hard drive?
I don't think I can fit ALL of my files on my internal hard drive, so I'm not sure what to do. Is there a way to back up specific files/folders?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have encryption on? Did you somehow write to the disk after the incident?
Yes, it is formatted in NTFS from the factory.

I should try following the advice in this [article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124432/recovering-very-important-lost-data-from-ntfs-partition?rq=1).