# I cannot delete a folder in a USB drive

Tags: nautilus, usb-drive, directory

I've removed the USB key while the system was saying something like *finishing writing, DO NOT REMOVE USB stick* but I wasn’t looking at the screen so couldn't catch the on-screen warning.

Now I have a stuck folder in my drive. If I try to delete it I get an *input/output* error in Nautilus. The stick seems to work fine though.

Any advise on how to remove the folder? Need to format the stick?

Comment: Try to remove it from the command line. Plug it, `cd` there, then `ls` to find out the folder name from the bash opinion, and `rm -rf` it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like there are errors on the filesystem.

follow this link:

[How to repair a corrupted FAT32 file system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147228/how-to-repair-a-corrupted-fat32-file-system)

where they tell you how ro correct these errors. The pendrive is read-only as the computer is cannot make sense of the present state of the filesystem, and if ubuntu were to tashly write anything to it, it might cause data to be lost.

Comment: Good answer, but it's an NTFS :D

Answer (score 0):

Go to format USB than format your USB to any other format. Now format it back to the format you need. This should work =)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, Kira.  Please take the [tour].  Some small remarks about your answer: 1. "than" should be "then". 2. Saying "This should work" is not highly informative; can you better (explicitly) express what this will do and why it may or may not be a good idea? There will be many researchers that will not need this spelled out, but the minority that do will appreciate the clarity. 3. Please never include smileys in a post -- answers should only contain content that is vital to resolving the ask question, nothing more.