# Corrupt usb. Is there any way to fix it?

Tags: usb, mount, fat32, lsusb

I'm really new to Linux, so I might seems to be stupid from time to time. But anyways, I unplugged a USB flash memory from my computer, while running windows xp. I think that this got it corrupt in some way. I can't solve this problem in Windows. I heard that Linux seems to be much better at fixing this kinda problems.

I found [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147228/how-to-repair-a-corrupted-fat32-file-system). However I can't seems to find my usb device by using `mount` command. I can find it when looking at `lsusb`. The problem is that I can't find the device address.

---

**EDIT:**  I need to access some files from the USB device - 8GB FAR32. I only care about the word-documents on it, but it would be nice, if I could grab some .htm and .css files too. I can't open the usb flash memory because its corrupted.

- Is there a way to grab the files, or better fixing the usb.
  My linux machine is running Xubuntu, however I can grab standard Ubuntu if it's needed.

**EDIT2:**
`fdisk -l` gives me this

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 7743 MB, 7743995904 bytes
80 heads, 16 sectors/track, 11816 cylinders, total 15124992 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        8064    15124991     7558464    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Sorry for misspellings my main language is not English

Comment: Question is too vague to be answerable.  You need to provide details.

Comment: Ooo yeah I kinda forgot what I needed help with diden't i? :S I edited the first post with more details

Comment: I managed to fix it in Windows.
All is on [this forum](http://www.sweclockers.com/forum/6-lagring/1244183-usb-minne-funkar-ibland-behover-radda-filer). However it's written in swedish so use google translate and it might help you solve this problem to.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any data off it, here's how to get rid of everything and make an 'FAT' partition:

1. Search dash for 'disks' and open
2. Click the memory stick from the left
3. If there is anything shown under where it says 'Volumes', do this (otherwise skip):

3.1. Click it. If when you click it it shows these: [square] [line] [gear] click the square. If it shows these: [triangle] [line] [gear] that means it's not mounted.
3.2. When you've done that for all partitions (items in the box under 'Volumes'), click the gear in the app top right and choose format disk.
3.3. Choose 'Don't overwrite existing data' and 'Empty'.

1. Click where it says 'Free space' and click the plus in the bottom left of the box.
2. Drag the bar up to as far as it'll go, choose 'Don't overwrite existing data' and 'Compatible with everything (FAT)'.
3. Choose a name and click 'Create'.

Done!

Comment: Sadly I need to acess some files on it. And the company that sold it to me offerd me money back so I'll probely just get a new one or a better one. 
But thanks annyway