# Ubuntu USB Failed Install

Tags: usb, usb-drive

I tried to install Ubuntu on USB but it failed. Now my USB has 0 free and its not even booting. How can I restore the USB to reinstall the Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here about how to format a memory stick to FAT (compatible with everything): [Corrupt usb. Is there any way to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/357138/corrupt-usb-anny-way-to-fix/357208#357208)