# Erasing a corrupted flash drive

Tags: partitioning, gparted, data-corruption

I have a 2TB flash drive that was corrupted when I pulled it out without ejecting it first. I am trying to erase the files, delete the partition, and reformat the whole thing. All the obvious things are not working though.

Disks couldn't overwrite the data because it's read-only, GParted has 2 things it will do, if it's already unmounted then GParted simply crashes, if the drive is mounted, GParted will open and then crash when I unmount it. I even attempted to use unetbootin to overwrite the files with an Ubuntu iso and it didn't work. I tried changing the files to read/write but that didn't work either. Any suggestions?

```
$ sudo fsck -n /dev/sdb
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 1.9 TiB, 2097152000000 bytes, 4096000000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00095e6d

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 4095999999 4095997952  1.9T  b W95 FAT32

$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 230.6G  0 part /
└─sda5   8:5    0   7.9G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   1   1.9T  1 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1   1.9T  1 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

result of sudo dmesg | grep -E 'usb|sdb'
http://pastebin.ca/3766662

The usb says it is a Transcend but I think it's a knock off, it shows up in the results linked above as generic mass storage.

Comment: Try using `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/<YOUR_USB_DISK>` but be **very careful not to erase your hard disk.**

Comment: Like @MarkYisri said but if you always add `count=1` then only first 512 bytes are overriden and you can rebuild lost MBR whey you goof up.

Comment: result of dd is [code]dd: failed to open '/dev/sdb1': Read-only file system[/code]

Comment: use the tilde ` when writing code

Comment: `dd: failed to open '/dev/sdb1': Read-only file system`

Comment: Does your flash have a little switch on it which can make it read-only? If so, try putting it in the other position.

Comment: It should not be `sdb1` but `sdb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a hardware issue. The people I bought the drive from were jerks and they hacked it to make it think it was 2 TB when it was only 120+ GB. I went over that data cap and the drive didn't know what to do so it crashed. There was no fixing it so I threw it away.

Comment: Because a 2TB flash drive costs $1,000 I would call that criminal

Comment: Maybe the drive works as a [data] drive if you create a 120 GB partition on it. Can you still pick it up from the waste-paper basket, or has it left your house?

Comment: unbelievable. what company?

Comment: I bought it from a site called Wish, I only paid like $10 for it. I didn't question it because wish is known for selling $500 items super cheap. I couldn't tell you exactly where it came from but reformatting was not an option. As they explained to me at the YSU tech desk, to do anything with it (including deleting files or reformatting it) would require a little space to work with. The hack made it so that it would fill up and then keep trying to put more data in until it inevitably crashed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and recreate a GPT table on your key. GPT is the equivalent of MBR for big disks, such as yours. Recreating a table will erase everything, including corrupted GPT data (if it's what's corrupted) and recreate a table from scratch.

To do this :

1. Check the key is unmounted and, if not, open a terminal and type `sudo umount /dev/<YOUR_DISK>` (needs admin rights though). Be careful : "YOUR_DISK" should be something like `/dev/sdb`, and not `/dev/sdb1` (`sdb` is the whole disk while `sdb1` is only a partition
2. Then, type `sudo parted /dev/<YOUR_DISK>`. Same rule applies to "YOUR_DISK" here. This will bring a prompt looking like this : `(parted)`
3. Once you get to that prompt, type `mklabel gpt`, which will recreate the new GPT table, and erase all partitions with their data.
4. You can then exit the prompt by typing `quit`

Another solution, as the disk appears to be formatted in FAT32, is to try and fix it using this command :

`sudo dosfsck -w -r -l -a -v -t /dev/sdb1`

(taken from a previous AskUbuntu answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147228/how-to-repair-a-corrupted-fat32-file-system#147237)). If the command doesn't exist, you may install the package `dosfstools` with `apt-get`

Comment: `$ sudo parted /dev/sdb1
Warning: Unable to open /dev/sdb1 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sdb1
has been opened read-only.
GNU Parted 3.2                                                            
Using /dev/sdb1
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) mklabel gpt                                                      
.
.
.
Error: Can't write to /dev/sdb1, because it is opened read-only.`

Comment: the command should be `sudo parted /dev/sdb`, otherwise it throws your "read-only" error

Comment: oh my bad, still same result, can't write because it's read-only

Comment: Have you tried unmounting it before ? Could you post the output of these two commands : `sudo fsck -n /dev/sdb` and `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb` ?

Comment: Could you edit your question and post them here (in your question) ?

Comment: idk why I didn't think of that in the first place lol but there it is

Comment: Could you also add `lsblk` ? (doesn't require sudo)

Comment: `lsblk` output added

Comment: What about trying this : `sudo parted /dev/sdb mklabel gpt` ? What is the name of your drive (what mark) ?

Comment: no change, still can't write because it's read-only.

Comment: Ok, could you then specify the mark as well as the output of `sudo dmesg | grep -E 'usb|sdb' `

Comment: idk what you mean by mark but the output of that is huge and I don't understand what it means

Comment: By "mark" I mean if it's SanDisk, Corsair, etc. (I know I am not very explicit, english isn't my native language...). Don't worry for the output of dmesg, it's ok if you can't provide it

Comment: link added to a pastebin with the dmesg output

Comment: I just came over this : `sudo dosfsck -w -r -l -a -v -t /dev/sdb1`, from a previous answer in AskUbuntu [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/147228/how-to-repair-a-corrupted-fat32-file-system#147237), which will fix it automatically, as it seems you have a FAT32 file system

Comment: okay I've had this running since I got up this morning and there is a massive output, but for the past few hours it hasn't moved, it's just been displaying `/ÑEoèF≤┴τ.g j
  Start cluster beyond limit (4109120626 > 63984347). Truncating file.
/ÑEoèF≤┴τ.g j
  File size is 4102307328 bytes, cluster chain length is 0 bytes.
  Truncating file to 0 bytes.
Checking for bad clusters.
` as the latest output.