# How to fix "Input/output error" on USB Flash drive?

Tags: usb

I am using a 64GB flash drive with Ubuntu, and I still can read and write to it. But when I navigate to a certain folder is gives me the error message

```
Error when getting information for file '/media/alexander/D0f9-E846/Music/Misc/t....": Input/output error
```

Instead of the points there are some strange characters to see. I am not able to delete that directory.

The format is "W95 FAT32" and should stay in that format.

I assume formatting the flash drive will help only? Or is there another way of fixing this issue?

Comment: Formating is something to try but it's likely not to help because I/O errors typically indicate a defective drive.

Comment: Oh I see. And there is no way to somehow isolate the defective areas...?

Comment: AFAIK there isn't, that's not how flash memory works.

Comment: Try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/147228/how-to-repair-a-corrupted-fat32-file-system