# My file system is readonly

Tags: filesystem

I'm new to Ubuntu. Recently, I plugged in an external hard drive of a friend to my Dell inspiron laptop. After transferring some files to the hard drive and unplugged, my PC started misbehaving. I could no longer create nor save files to my hard disk. I have restarted my PC over a million times, I have searched everywhere on Google but to no avail. Please help, just tell me what to do, please

Comment: Could this be the same issue as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008377/how-do-i-change-pen-drive-from-read-mode-to-full-access)?

Comment: Please explain how (the commands) you transferred the files and how you unplugged the external drive (umount?).