# Input/Output error on usb drive

Tags: usb, fsck

I have been trying to recover my usb flash drive and have been looking into this question

> [How to repair a corrupted FAT32 file system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147228/how-to-repair-a-corrupted-fat32-file-system)

I can not write data or anything into my drive it just gives me the error Input/output error 
So I tried

```
sudo dosfsck -t -a -w /dev/sdb1
```

and result was like this

> fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
>   0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
>    Automatically removing dirty bit.
>   There are differences between boot sector and its backup.
>   This is mostly harmless. Differences: (offset:original/backup)
>     67:a5/6a, 68:ea/9d, 69:23/81, 70:54/7c
>     Not automatically fixing this.
>   /.Trash-1000
>     Contains a free cluster (1002). Assuming EOF.

After this it gives error of each file in the drive like this

> Cluster 3 (50031) is unreadable. Skipping it.
>   /FRIENDS/Copy of DSC00146.JPG

and then at the end it gives me this

> Cluster 0 (52685) is unreadable. Skipping it. Write 4 bytes at
>   8024884:Input/output error

I couldn't recover my drive. I am asking here after trying my best. Please help me. Thanks

Note : I am using ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Please also tell me if there is a problem with hardware that can not be fixed ......

Comment: I/O errors usually mean faulty hardware. Do you care about the data on the USB drive? You should back it up somewhere then as soon as possible. After that, I would completely zero out the device (overwrite it completely with zeroes) using `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=4M` (replace sdX with the USB's device name as shown in `lsblk`. Make sure it is correct, whatever you specify here will be erased, you don't want to accidentally put your hard disk here!). Sometimes this overwriting gets a device back to work, or at least you will know for sure if it's dead. After that you can reformat it

Comment: This doesn't work ....

Comment: *What* doesn't work? If you encountered any error messages, please [edit] your question and describe what exactly did and what happened by adding the full commands you ran and their complete output. We can't guess what's going on on your machine unless you tell us.