# SD card permissions

Tags: permissions, sd-card

I keep buying SD cards and they keep locking me out by denying me permission to delete files. This issue is becoming a real problem. How can I permanently make my SD cards read and write capable? Money is an issue, and I use a trail camera to keep an eye on my front porch when I order something from Amazon. The card is a SanDisk 8gb micro sd hc formatted fat 32, cylinder. It does it with all makes and models of ad cards. I've been battling this since I installed Ubuntu 10 yrs ago. There is no rhyme or reason as to when the issue occurs, sometimes its three swaps from camera to PC sometimes its twenty. Hundreds of of other people are asking the same question on the internet.

Need permission!

Comment: Are tyhe cards being used by the camera? With what file system?

Comment: The card is a SanDisk 8gb micro sd hc formatted fat 32, cylinder. It does it with all makes and models of ad cards. I've been battling this since I installed Ubuntu 10 yrs ago

Comment: But when does it happen? Is it after using it in the camera?

Comment: And **FAT32 does not support "permissions"** but cards about to die may become "read-only". This is an entirely different situation. And I need you to describe *how* you've been using the cards in order to determine were the problem starts or even *if* there's an actual problem other than normal wear.

Comment: I put the card in the trail camera when occasionally,  turn it on and it captures video of what goes on in the yard. I have some good wildlife video. In the morning I put the card in my Ubuntu computer to review the video and delete what I don't want and move what I want to  my hard drive.  I do this til the card goes read only. Then I can only format it to remove all the files. It's a pain to continually review old video from false alerts

Comment: Pleas [edit] the question to add additional information like the one you just provided in a comment. Also please explain *when* is it that you noticed the "read-only" status. Is it right after using it in the camera or after some time going back and forth from the camera to PC and camera again? Roughly how does it take to the card to be unusable? Also, nice to know you have good wildlife video but it doesn't help troubleshooting your reported problem.

Comment: Sorry, this has nothing to do with Ubuntu. Somehow your camera is corrupting the cards - or you're removing it while the camera is still writing to it -. It's either the camera or improper use, nothing to do with your PC or Ubuntu and as such off-topic in  this site.

Comment: I’d try [repairing a corrupted FAT32 file system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147228/how-to-repair-a-corrupted-fat32-file-system). If the checks give any errors, please add them to your question’s body!